# Need hibernate properties for mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I can't seem to find an example of hibernate properties for mysql.

Is there a link that has an example?

I have one for hsql:

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>      -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
                hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
                hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
                hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/firsthibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.password">r</property>
 <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <!--  thread is the short name for
      org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext
      and let Hibernate bind the session automatically to the thread
    -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- this will show us all sql statements -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="de/laliluna/example/Honey.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current Spring config file I think it would be:

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>      -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <value>
                        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                        hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
                        hibernate.connection.username=dbuser
                        hibernate.connection.password=dbpass
                        hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
                        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
                        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
                        hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
                        hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
                </value>
        </property>
</bean>
```